# Berryboot Headless installation help!

Tags: software-installation, berryboot

Yesterday I got my first Raspberry Pi (4 B) and I set it up on raspbian. I'm completely new to this kind of operations, but I managed to complete the installation. Today I wanted to take a step further, installing two OS on the same micro SD card. I found that one of the possible solutions is Berryboot. But unfortunately I don't have a keyboard/mouse nor a display to use right now, just my MacBook.

I followed the instruction to install BerryBoot, but I can't manage to use vnc to proceed with the installation. Of course I put into the SD the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file and added to `cmdline.txt` the following:

`vncinstall ipv4=192.168.88.88/255.255.255.0/192.168.88.1/wlan0`

on the same line. When I boot the Raspberry Pi I'm able to ping it from terminal, I see from my router that it is connected, but I cannot see it through VNC.
Any help would be truly appreciated!

EDIT:

Okay, I think I made a little step further. Editing the `cmdline.txt` I managed to change the Pi IP. I mean, now with `arp -a` on my Mac terminal I see the IP I specified associated with it. I try to connect to it using VNC but now it asks me for a password. I know that with `vncpasswd` I can change that, but I do not have access to the Pi terminal (as I said in a comment below, ssh doesn't work, neither if I put the blank ssh file in the micro SD). I was thinking, maybe giving instructions to change vnc password in `cmdline.txt` will work? How should I write that?

Comment: Two thoughts - the wpa_supplicant must have the country code in it.  There are also very specific restrictions on VNC in this situation documented at https://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot/headless_installation

Comment: Yes, the wpa_supplicant already has my country code. And, again, yes, I already followed that guide, with no luck

Comment: How about just hitting return?  Maybe a different client? Did you set a password on Berryboot itself (used to stop deleing images)?  Wrong keyboard language maybe?  Sorry nothing definite as a fix and you may have thought of these!  Quick check on the source points to libvnc and tight_vnc Maybe that will help? https://github.com/maxnet/berryboot/search?q=vnc&unscoped_q=vnc

Comment: Hi @Futurballa can you explain me in detail all the steps you have followed?
cmdline where is placed? and what ip you have write on it?
for proceed installation is sufficient open a vnc client like realvnc and digit ip 192.168.88.88?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

( Entirely skipping questions of vnc, but answering how to talk to the headless Pi. )
Try putty, there is a Mac OS client, with ssh enabled on the Pi, ( create a file named ssh in /boot on the micro SD, ( that directory may show as a drive named "boot" with the card plugged int the Mac. ) doesn't need any content, just to be there ).

Putty will give you a login terminal.  Use "sudo halt" or "sudo reboot" as need.
If you are new to Unix - Linux --- try man -k ssh at the terminal.
Running Windows for cad reasons, I use xrdp to get a X window display.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, with Berryboot creating a ssh blank file doesn't work. With raspbian flashed in the SD card it worked tho.